# Where is Firefox's auto-fill information stored?

Tags: firefox

I need to retrieve one text-box text on an Ubuntu installation I can't boot anymore (thank you Fedora!) on one specific website.

Where is the form information stored and how can I retrieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form history is saved in a SQLite database file named `formhistory.sqlite` (replace `$HOME` by your Ubuntu home directory, and `XXXXXXXX.default` by your Firefox profile name):

```
$HOME/.mozilla/firefox/XXXXXXX.default/formhistory.sqlite
```

Instead of reinstalling add-ons, bookmarks, etc., you can just copy your Firefox settings to your new system. Make your file browser show hidden files and copy the `.mozilla` folder to your new home folder.

Alternatively, close existing Firefox instances and run Firefox with the old profile folder:

```
firefox -profile /path/to/old/home/.mozilla/firefox/XXXXXXXX.default
```